# Why is the jQuery hover method not working in this case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get a button in the bootstrap popover to change class when I hover over it using jQuery but for some reason, it is not working. I have looked everywhere and I am using the same method as everybody else for hover events in jQuery but, for some reason, it is just not working.

I am trying to change the classes from `btn btn-default` to `btn btn-success` on hover. I realize that this could be achieved using CSS(the color change) but this is supposed to work and it is not working and I wanna know why and resolve it.

I am using : Bootstrap 3.3.6, jQuery

The Entire HTML file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Easy ToDo</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.native/1.0.2/bootstrap-native.min.js"></script> -->
    <script>
        function checkTaskStatus(checkbox) {
            var tasktext = document.getElementById('tasktext');
            var taskrow = document.getElementById('taskrow');
            if (checkbox.checked){
                taskrow.className = "active";
                tasktext.className = "text-muted";
                tasktext.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("taskrow").className = "warning";
                document.getElementById('tasktext').className = "text-success";
                tasktext.style.textDecoration = "none";
            }
        }

        function changeBtn(button) {
            var temp = button.className;
            if(temp === "btn btn-primary") {
                button.className = "btn btn-danger";
                button.innerText = "Close";
            }
            else {
                button.className = "btn btn-primary";
                button.innerText = "Add New Task";
            }
        }


    </script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
                html: true,
                title: 'New Task',
                trigger: 'click',
                content: function () {
                            return $('.popoverContent').html();
                },
                placement: 'right'
            });


        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btntask").hover(function () {
                $(this).removeClass('btn btn-default');
                $(this).addClass('btn btn-success');
            }, function () {
                $(this).removeClass('btn btn-success');
                $(this).addClass('btn btn-default');
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <h1 style="border: 2px solid rebeccapurple; margin-top: 0; background-color: rebeccapurple; color: white; padding-left: 0.6em; padding-bottom: 0.1em; margin-bottom: 1.5em;">An Easy To - Do Web App!</h1>


       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-bottom: 15px; margin-left: 10px;" data-toggle="popover" onclick="changeBtn(this)">Add New Task</button>
        <div class="popoverContent hide">
            <label for="newTask">Task:</label>
            <textarea rows="3" name="newTask" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Task HTML"></textarea>
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" style="margin-top: 10px;" id="btntask">Done</button>
        </div>

        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: auto"> </th>
                    <th style="width: auto">#</th>
                    <th style="width: auto">Date</th>
                    <th style="width: auto">Task</th>
                    <th style="width: auto">Notes</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="warning" id="taskrow">
                    <td><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="checkTaskStatus(this)"></label></div></td>

                    <td scope="row" style="font-weight: bold;">1</td>

                    <td><p style="font-style: italic; font-weight: bold;">7th May, 2016</p></td>

                    <td class="text-success" id="tasktext" style="text-decoration: none;"><h5 id="task-heading" style="margin-top: 0; text-decoration: underline; font-weight: bold;">Tesla Share Purchase Reasearch:</h5>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Find out how an Australian citizen can purchase shares in an American company (e.g. Tesla) which is not listed on the ASX (Australian Stock Exchange)</li>
                            <li>Prepare a brief list of the steps, costs and general time frame for an Australian to get set up to purchase share in American companies</li>
                            <li>Please also state the current stock price of Apple, Google (potentially Alphabet as they are the parent??), Facebook, Twitter and Tesla</li>
                            <li>Bullet points are fine</li>
                            <li>Please include any relevant links</li>
                            <li>Spend no longer than 1.5 – 2 hours on this</li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>

                    <td><div class="form-group">
                            <textarea class="form-control input-md" rows="4" placeholder="Notes"></textarea>
                            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="submit" style="margin-top: 10px;">Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>



</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Note that, I am fairly new to jQuery and JS so if there is any inaccuracies on my part, please point them out.

Comment: Your code is just working fine see the working demo, I've just remove extra markup http://codepen.io/harishgadiya/pen/GZzOZo

Comment: I don't see the relevance. Your link has a dropdown and no hover functions

Comment: My code is not working fine, the button with the ID #btnTask should change classes but it is not.

Comment: Its changing see updated pen, Actually i've just overwrite the pen http://codepen.io/harishgadiya/pen/GZzOZo

Comment: You're half correct, I tested it this way and it did change, but when I put it inside a popover it doesn't for some reason.

Comment: So you have not mention this popover thing, like just do one thing add your hover function after the popover open, If its not work for you paste your code into codepen then i will fix

Comment: I have mentioned that in the first line and alright I will try that and update the question.

Comment: As you and Sukhmeet Singh pointed out, I have corrected the code and provided my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is when you are trying to add the hover state on the popover , the popover element is not yet available. The element is only added when you click. Hence, the function in `$(document).ready()` actually adds no hover state. 
Instead use jQuery `.on`

Comment: Can you provide a code example? It would really help, thanks

Comment: I have written my answer below, thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

If your hover has not much work to do, you can opt for css hover

```
#element:hover
{
    /*Add your css after hover here*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Sukhmeet Singh the popover did not appear until on click and not on document.ready.

So I tweaked my script from :

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btntask").hover(function () {
                $(this).removeClass('btn btn-default');
                $(this).addClass('btn btn-success');
            }, function () {
                $(this).removeClass('btn btn-success');
                $(this).addClass('btn btn-default');
            });
        });
```

To :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').on('click', function () {
                $("#btntask").hover(function () {
                    $(this).removeClass('btn btn-default');
                    $(this).addClass('btn btn-success');
                }, function () {
                    $(this).removeClass('btn btn-success');
                    $(this).addClass('btn btn-default');
                });
            });
        });
```

And it worked. The popover is non-existent in document.ready but appears there when I click on the button with the property `[data-toggle="popover"]` and thus, when I target the button I want to highlight then, it does it.